# Print a string, accept user input and validating it using a private String method?

Tags: java, methods

For my programming class, I have the following assignment:

> In this assignment you will write a program that will model a pet
>   store. The program will have a Pet class to model individual pets and
>   the Assignment5 class will contain the main and act as the pet store.
>   Users will be able to view the pets, make them age a year at a time,
>   add a new pet, and adopt any of the pets.

I have finished making the Pet class, but am experiencing difficulties with this specific step of the assignment:

> Create a private static String method which prints out the main menu
>   of the program. It then accepts a String from the user and returns
>   their choice. The commands to list are as follows. a. List the pets in
>   the store. b. Age up the pets. c. Add a new pet. d. Adopt a pet. e.
>   Quit. i. Your method must verify that the user typed in a valid input
>   before returning the input.

```
private static String mainMenu(){
    return "\n" + "A. List the pets in the store." +
                    "\n" + "B. Age up the pets" + 
                    "\n" + "C. Add a new pet" + 
                    "\n" + "D. Adopt a pet" + 
                    "\n" + "E. Quit";
}
```

The problem is that I can't find a way for the method to print the menu AND accept and validate user input. Can you help me incorporate the code below into my private method?

```
// Ask for letter 
    System.out.println("Type the letter to make your selection." + mainMenu());
    char letter = Character.toUpperCase((scan.next().charAt(0)));

    // Check if letter is valid. If not, ask the user to input another letter.
    while (!(letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'E')){
        System.out.println("That is not one of the options. Input another letter.");
        letter = Character.toUpperCase((scan.next().charAt(0)));
    }
```

Comment: *Step 1:* Make the method actually `print()` the menu, instead of returning a string with the menu. --- *Step 2:* Have your code after the printing of the menu. --- *Step 3:* `return` the value entered by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where your scanner is being declared right now but you want something like the following

```
private static String mainMenu(Scanner scan){
    String menu = "\n" + "A. List the pets in the store." +
            "\n" + "B. Age up the pets" +
            "\n" + "C. Add a new pet" +
            "\n" + "D. Adopt a pet" +
            "\n" + "E. Quit";

    System.out.println("Type the letter to make your selection." + menu);
    char letter = Character.toUpperCase((scan.next().charAt(0)));

    // Check if letter is valid. If not, ask the user to input another letter.
    while (!(letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'E')){
        System.out.println("That is not one of the options. Input another letter.");
        letter = Character.toUpperCase((scan.next().charAt(0)));
    }

    return letter + "";
}
```

I am using `return letter + "";` because letter is a char, and your function is returning a string so an easy way to convert it is to concatenate the empty quote

It seems like you already have a scanner declared, in that case you could pass it in as a parameter as I have, or you can have an instance variable for the scanner, ultimately that part is up to how you have the rest of your class structured

Answer (score 0):

The point is that in your implementation you are returning the menu at the very first line, so the method can't have additional behavior, I've created a class for this example using most of your code, hope you can use it, I also moved the valid input check to a separate method as some kind of good practice :)

```
package stackOverflow;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pregunta {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String choice = menu();
        System.out.println("User input: " + choice);
    }

    public static String menu() {
        String menu = "\n" + "A. List the pets in the store." +
                "\n" + "B. Age up the pets" +
                "\n" + "C. Add a new pet" +
                "\n" + "D. Adopt a pet" +
                "\n" + "E. Quit";
        System.out.println(menu);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.next();
        char letter = Character.toUpperCase((input.charAt(0)));

        // Check if letter is valid. If not, ask the user to input another letter.
        while (!isValidInput(letter)) {
            System.out.println("That is not one of the options. Input another letter.");
            input = scan.next();
            letter = Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(0));
        }
        return input;
    }

    public static boolean isValidInput(char letter) {
        return (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'E');
    }
}
```